# LinAlgError when modeling ARIMA

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I'm facing a weird problem when I'm modeling ARIMA and checking MSE.

Here's code that I'm trying out.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import sys

split_point = int(len(value_series) * 0.66)
train, test = value_series.values[0:split_point], value_series.values[split_point:]
history = [float(x) for x in train]
predictions = list()

for t in range(len(test)):
    try:
        model = ARIMA(history, order=(2,1,2))
        model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
        output = model_fit.forecast()
        yhat = output[0]
        predictions.append(yhat)
        obs = test[t]
        history.append(obs)
        print('# %s predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (t, yhat, obs))
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        pass

error = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
print('Test MSE: %.3f' % error)
```

The error that I got is `Unexpected error: <class 'numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError'>` on the line `model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)`.
The error came out from 282th to the end of data which has the 343 length of list and still I couldn't find any solutions and causes.

Anyway, the outputs of length of the predictions and test are 282 and 343 respectively. I don't know why predictions couldn't attach yhat, which means yhat couldn't be assigned by output from arima.fit.forcast()...

+) And that's with `SVD did not converge` error.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
X = value_series.values
size = int(len(X) * 0.66)
trn, tst = X[0:size], X[size:len(X)]
hsty = [x.astype(float) for x in trn]
pred = []
for i in range(len(tst)):
    try:
        model = ARIMA(hsty, order=(3,1,1))
        model_fit = model.fit(disp=0, start_ar_lags = None)
        residuals = DataFrame(model_fit.resid)
        out = model_fit.forecast()
        yhat = out[0]
        predictions.append(yhat)
        obs = tst[i]
        hsty.append(obs)
        print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
    except:
        pass
if len(tst)>len(pred):
    err = mean_squared_error(tst[:len(pred)], pred)
else:
    err = mean_squared_error(tst, pred[:len(tst)])
print(f'Test MSE : {err:.3f}')
```

Comment: This 'try.. except' just escapes the sucked data samples, which can lead the wrong alignment when evaluated.